# Make added route persistent after restart

Tags: rhel, route

I am adding this line to add a route `Route add –net 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0 gw 95.98.108.14`

However, when I restart the machine, the route is gone and I had to insert it again.

How can I make it persistent. I am on Red Hat 6.5 Santiago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add your comman to be executed on the startup of the machine , or make your route persistant, in order to do that your need to edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0` file to define static routes for eth0 interface. This configuration will be persistent even after the system is rebooted.

```
 example:
 # route add -net 192.168.100.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.10.1 dev eth0

 will be:

 GATEWAY0=192.168.10.1 
 NETMASK0=255.255.255.0 
 ADDRESS0=192.168.100.0

 GATEWAY1=10.64.34.1 
 NETMASK1= 255.255.255.240 
 ADDRESS1=10.64.34.10

 # service network restart
```

more info [here](https://www.cloudibee.com/static-route-linux/)